# Simulate button press

Tags: android

I have this resource for a `Button`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/CLR_GREEN" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/CLR_GREEN_DARK" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And I refer to this button in code as `greenBtn`

How do I simulate its pressure without firing its `onClick` event? i.e. how do I make it change its background color as if it was pressed, stay in this state for half a second and then be back in its original state?

Comment: @Macarese I'm doing a Simon Says clone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`View#setPressed(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPressed%28boolean%29)

---

I think your `<item>` without any states is overriding your first `<item>`. Try making it `<item android:state_pressed="false">`

Comment: how about if you try that? :)

Comment: It's weird, the last one in the list is supposed to be the default one if none of the others match. I haven't played with the statelist stuff much but I do remember reading that it is pretty poorly documented and problematic to get right.

Comment: when I actually press the button it does change its background color, so I'm pretty sure I don't have to touch the xml.